# Method inside of a class always returns same output while the same logic outside of the class works

Tags: python-3.x, class, printing, return

I have this block of code inside of a class. No matter what data I pass into the class, this will always return "Loss".

```
def win_loss_unadj(self):
    if self.side == "Long" and (self.getMAE > self.getStop) and (self.getMFE >= self.unadj_T2):
        return "T2_Win"
    elif self.side == "Long" and (self.getMAE > self.getStop) and (self.getMFE >= self.unadj_T1):
        return "Win"
    elif self.side == "Short" and (self.getMAE < self.getStop) and (self.getMFE <= self.unadj_T2):
        return "T2_Win"            
    elif self.side == "Short" and (self.getMAE < self.getStop) and (self.getMFE <= self.unadj_T1):
        return "Win"        
    else:
        return "Loss"
```

When I use the same logic outside of the class (using print() instead of return), I get the correct results with the same data.

```
for i in range(len(tradeList)):       
    if Trade.side(tradeList[i]) == "Long" and (Trade.getMAE(tradeList[i]) > Trade.getStop(tradeList[i])) and (Trade.getMFE(tradeList[i]) >= Trade.unadj_T2(tradeList[i])):
        print("T2_Win")
    elif Trade.side(tradeList[i]) == "Long" and (Trade.getMAE(tradeList[i]) > Trade.getStop(tradeList[i])) and (Trade.getMFE(tradeList[i]) >= Trade.unadj_T1(tradeList[i])):
        print("Win")
    elif Trade.side(tradeList[i]) == "Short" and (Trade.getMAE(tradeList[i]) < Trade.getStop(tradeList[i])) and (Trade.getMFE(tradeList[i]) <= Trade.unadj_T2(tradeList[i])):
        print("T2_Win")
    elif Trade.side(tradeList[i]) == "Short" and (Trade.getMAE(tradeList[i]) < Trade.getStop(tradeList[i])) and (Trade.getMFE(tradeList[i]) <= Trade.unadj_T1(tradeList[i])):
        print("Win")    
    else:
        print("Loss")
```

Now, I might be grossly misunderstanding the return command or class methods in general. I am not experienced with python at all and for the life of me I can't figure out what's wrong here.

I checked if there was something wrong with the objects themselves, but there isn't. All the data is correct, so the issue MUST be in the first section of code I posted.

Comment: What is your class method's output when you run `print(self.side, self.getMAE, self.getStop, self.getMFE, self. unadj_T2, self.unadj_T1)`? It's nice to see other traders on here!

Comment: Always happy to see traders :) I get no output if I run print in the method. If I run it outside, I get this: <function Trade.side at 0x000001B41E63B510> <function Trade.getMAE at 0x000001B41E63B158> <function Trade.getStop at 0x000001B41E63B378> <function Trade.getMFE at 0x000001B41E63B268> <function Trade.unadj_T2 at 0x000001B41E63B6A8> <function Trade.unadj_T1 at 0x000001B41E63B620>

Comment: Please post your class.